# Simplifying a parametric equation for the formula of a circle given to point on opposite sides

Tags: trigonometry, circles, parametric

Given two points that are 180 degrees from each other at points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ respectively you can find a circle with all points of the form $$x=\cos \left(t\right)^2\left(\tan \left(t\right)\left(x_2\tan \left(t\right)-y_2+y_1\right)+x_1\right)$$ $$y=\sin \left(t\right)^2\left(x_2\tan \left(t\right)-y_2+y_1\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(2t\right)x_1-x_2\tan \left(t\right)+y_2$$ $$0\le t\le \pi $$

Obviously this is kinda a monster of a parametric set of equations and I was wondering if anyone had any advice on how to go along solving simplifying it, ideally in in a $y=x$ form or something similar.

Comment: At $t=0$ and $t=\pi$ you have $x=x_1$ and $y=y_2$. Is that correct?

Comment: At $t=0$ and at $t=\pi$ $x$ does equal $x_1$ and $y$ does equal $y_2$. Why do you ask?

Comment: And at $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $y$ is undefined.

Comment: Just wanted to be sure. So both $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_1,y_2)$ are points on the circle.

Comment: Both points are on the circle, and by the way as $\lim_{t\to pi/2}$  $x=x_2$ and $y=y_2$.

Comment: OK, I was about to check out the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these two points are $180º$ from each other, then they are on opposite sides of the circle.

Therefore, the circle's center is $\displaystyle \left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right)$.

The radius of the circle would then be $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$

You would then have

$\displaystyle x(t)=\frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)+\frac{1}{2}\cos(t)\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$

$\displaystyle y(t)=\frac{1}{2}(y_1+y_2)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(t)\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$

**Update: In order to fit the constraints on $t$, changing the argument of $\sin$ and $\cos$ from $t$ to $2t$ works**

$\boxed{\displaystyle x(t)=\frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2t)\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}}$

$\boxed{\displaystyle y(t)=\frac{1}{2}(y_1+y_2)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2t)\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}}$

Comment: Notice I just averaged the coordinates, and then took the distance to be the diameter, so half that distance would be the radius.

Comment: In your example the range of t needs to extended from [0,pi] to [0,2pi]. Neat

Comment: sorry @AaronQuitta

Comment: This does not give the same results for $t=0$ as the original formulation.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it would... @JohnWaylandBales

Comment: The original formulation gives $x(0)=x_1$ and $y(0)=y_2$. This formulation gives $y(0)=\frac{1}{2}(y_1+y_2)$

Comment: no it didn't. the only change in my formulations are that the circle is traced out faster. the center and the path of travel maintain the same @JohnWaylandBales

Comment: I see. I misunderstood the goal. I thought it was to reformulate the original $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ so that the reformulation was simpler yet equal to the original formulation. That is what my formulation accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
x&=&\cos^2 \left(t\right)\left(\tan \left(t\right)\left(x_2\tan \left(t\right)-y_2+y_1\right)+x_1\right)\\
y&=&\sin^2 \left(t\right)\left(x_2\tan \left(t\right)-y_2+y_1\right)+\frac{1}{2}x_1\sin \left(2t\right)-x_2\tan \left(t\right)+y_2
\end{eqnarray}

The points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ lie at opposite ends of the diameter of a circle of radius $r$ and center $(h,k)=\left(\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2},\dfrac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right)$.

Thus the translation $\left(\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2},\dfrac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right)\rightarrow(0,0)$ moves the circle to a circle with radius $r$ about the origin and

\begin{eqnarray}
(x_1,y_1)\rightarrow\left(\frac{x_1-x_2}{2},\frac{y_1-y_2}{2}\right)=(u,v)\\
(x_2,y_2)\rightarrow\left(-\frac{x_1-x_2}{2},-\frac{y_1-y_2}{2}\right)=(-u,-v)\\
\end{eqnarray}

This translates equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ as follows

\begin{eqnarray}
x&=&\phantom{-1}u\cos(2t)+v\sin(2t)\\
y&=&-v\cos(2t)+u\sin(2t)
\end{eqnarray}

Translating back to the original position gives

\begin{eqnarray}
x&=&\phantom{-1}u\cos(2t)+v\sin(2t)+h\\
y&=&-v\cos(2t)+u\sin(2t)+k
\end{eqnarray}

Replacing the original variables gives

\begin{eqnarray}
x(t)&=&\frac{1}{2}[(x_1+x_2)+(x_1-x_2)\cos(2t)+(y_1-y_2)\sin(2t)]\\
y(t)&=&\frac{1}{2}[(y_1+y_2)-(y_1-y_2)\cos(2t)+(x_1-x_2)\sin(2t)]
\end{eqnarray}

Notice that for any $t\in[0,\pi]$ this formulation gives the same results as the original formulation.